# Signing an iOS application manually and changing its app Id

Tags: ios, code-signing, codesign

I'd like to know if there is a way to just compile my iOS project without any signing and doing the signing myself after?

I'd like to be able to change the app Id and some resources, but I don't want to have to recompile the source code everytime with xcode-build.

Far from now, I'm able to change resources of the app and resign an IPA file but I cannot change the app Id as it is hard coded into the binary. See the link below for more details.

http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/code-signing-changes-in-xcode-4/

Comment: What do you want to do? This makes no sense.

Comment: Take one ipa, change the name (and the app Id) resign it with a different certificate. Without having the source code.

Comment: Well, typically, when an **.IPA** is created, it is already (or should have been already) signed using a developer certificate. This altogether sounds like a horrible idea anyway. Just copy the project and create different versions (with different bundle id's and names).

Comment: Ok, so when you build for arm, the compiler MUST sign the binary :(. Thanks for the help